# Slick - many to many relationship

Tags: scala, slick

I am working on a Library data model where each book can have multiple authors and vice versa (many to many).
I want to pass a list of books to a html view page that each book includes a list of its author(s).
To do that I have defined the following tables for book and authors:

```
  private class BookTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Book](tag, "book") {

    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def name = column[String]("name")

    def publishDate = column[Date]("publish_date")

    def memberId = column[Option[Long]]("member_id")

    def member = foreignKey("member_fk",memberId,members)(_.id)

    type Data = (Long, String, Date, Option[Long])

    def constructBook: Data => Book = {
      case (id, name, publishDate, memberId) =>
        Book(id, name, publishDate, memberId)
    }

    def extractBook: PartialFunction[Book, Data] = {
      case Book(id, name, publishDate, memberId, _) =>
        (id, name, publishDate, memberId)
    }

    def * = (id, name, publishDate, memberId) <> (constructBook, extractBook.lift)
  }


private class AuthorBookTable (tag: Tag) extends Table[AuthorBook](tag, "author_book") {


 def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

 def authorId = column[Long]("author_id")

 def bookId = column[Long]("book_id")

  def memberId = column[Option[Long]]("member_id")

  def author = foreignKey("author_fk",authorId,authors)(_.id)

  def book = foreignKey("book_fk",bookId,books)(_.id)

 def * = (id, authorId, bookId) <> ((AuthorBook.apply _).tupled, AuthorBook.unapply)
}


private class AuthorTable (tag: Tag) extends Table[Author](tag, "author") {

 def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

 def name = column[String]("name")

 def * = (id, name) <> ((Author.apply _).tupled, Author.unapply)
}
```

The book case class is as below:

```
case class Book(id: Long, name: String, publishDate: Date, memberId: Option[Long] = None, authors: Seq[Author]= Seq.empty)
{

  def updateAuthors(authorss: Seq[Author]) = {
    this.copy(authors=authorss)
  }
}
```

In controller I use the below:

```
  def getBooks = Action.async { implicit request =>
    repo.getBooks.map { books =>
      val booksWithAuthors=books.map( b=> {val updateB=b.updateAuthors( repo.getBookAuthors(b.id))
        updateB})
      Ok(Json.toJson(booksWithAuthors))
    }
  }
```

My question is about the getBookAuthors implementation shown below:

```
  implicit def waitForFuture[A](f:Future[A]) = {
    def res: A = Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
    res
  }

  def getBookAuthors(id: Long): Seq[Author] = {
    val result=db.run {
      val innerJoin = for {
        (ab, a) <- authorBooks join authors on (_.authorId === _.id)
      } yield (a, ab.bookId)
      innerJoin.filter(_._2 === id).sortBy(_._1.name).map(_._1).result
    }
    waitForFuture(result)
  }
```

My concern is that the getBookAuthors function is blocking and I am not sure if it's the best practice. Please advise if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saying, blocking methods are pretty bad in this context and you will lost the advantages of using a non-blocking library as Slick.

the `getBookAuthors` would be written as follows, returning a `Future[Seq[Author]]` thats needs to be managed in the caller

```
def getBookAuthors(id: Long): Future[Seq[Author]] =
  db.run {
    val innerJoin = for {
      (ab, a) <- authorBooks join authors on (_.authorId === _.id)
    } yield (a, ab.bookId)
    innerJoin.filter(_._2 === id).sortBy(_._1.name).map(_._1).result
  }
```

So the caller should be rewritten as:

```
def getBooks = Action.async { implicit request =>
  repo.getBooks.flatMap { books =>
    Future.sequence(
      books.map { b => 
        repo.getBookAuthors(b.id).map(authors => b.updateAuthors(authors))
      }
    ).map { booksWithAuthors =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(booksWithAuthors))
    }
  }
}
```

This means that, once you will have the `books: Seq[Book]` you will map over it to integrate the authors and this will end with a `Seq[Future[Book]]`.
Then it can be transformed into a `Future[Seq[Book]]` (with authors) with the `Future.sequence` method.
Finally you need to `flatMap` on the outer `Future` to move from `Future[Future[Seq[Book]]]` to a simpler `Future[Seq[Book]]`

This second snippet can be refactored in a more clean way taking advantage of the `for-comprehension` that is a syntactic sugar for the `flatMap`

```
private def addAuthorsToBooks(books: Seq[Book]): Future[Seq[Book]] = 
  Future.sequence(
    books.map { b => 
      repo.getBookAuthors(b.id).map(authors => b.updateAuthors(authors))
    }
  )

def getBooks = Action.async { implicit request =>
  for {
    books <- repo.getBooks
    booksWithAuthors <- addAuthorsToBooks(books)
  } yield Ok(Json.toJson(booksWithAuthors))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luca! It's working for me. I just cannot digest how when updateAuthors expects a Seq[Author] as a parameter, it accepts the result of getBookAuthors, which is a Future[Seq[Author]], without any compilation errors. In other words, where Future[Seq[Author]] is converted (or casted) to Seq[Author]?

Comment: As you can see `updateAuthors` is called inside a `Future.map`, so it's not correct when you say "is converted", but the parameter passed to the `map` method is a function used to transform the result of the `Future`. You can get more complete insights here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html